# Newbie C# Can I return result value from private bool to make as const string?

Tags: c#

Can I get my value results from bool into a const string?

```
public const string MState = "";
```

here is my code:

```
private bool GetStateByZipCode(string ZipOrPostalCode, string ST)
{
    try
    {
        string strServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyNGConnect_ConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "ngc_GetStateByZipCode";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipOrPostalCode", ZipOrPostalCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ST", ST);
        SqlDataReader reader = storedProcCommand.ExecuteReader();
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader["ZipOrPostalCode"].ToString().Equals(ZipOrPostalCode) &&
                      reader["ST"].ToString().Equals(ST))
                {
                    ST = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            con.Close ();
            reader.Close ();

            return ST;
        }
    }
    finally
    {

    }
```

Comment: Constants never change. You should define its value at compile-time.

Comment: I don't get the question. **Obviously** you can not store a string in a bool variable or vice versa. Can you *please* elaborate what your question really is?

Comment: @HenkHolterman In terms of C#, a `const string` is well defined.

Comment: Why are you returning `bool` when you obviously want to return `string`.  Also no you cannot assign a const at runtime.

Comment: You should really consider some using statements in that code.

Comment: After I get the result from the bool, can I then take that result and use it as a value for the rest of my code to call upon it?  In my example can ST = MState?

Comment: Apart from the const thing, why do you check the return value of the stored procedure against the same values used for the parameters? Are you not sure about the returned data?

Comment: Please write out a question where you describe *clearly* what you want to do. Also, when posting code, please make sure to post whether this is some hypothetical code you would like to work, or if it it's some piece of code you would *get to work*. The code as posted will not compile, nor can we see what you really what that constant to be used for.

Answer (score 2):

A `const` is not a variable, hence the name **Constant**. You cannot assign a value to a `const` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is 2 parts... the first is what everyone is telling you... no you cant do const string after the code has been compiled without some very bad coding practices.  I dont gather that is what you really want to ask.  I think what you are really asking is:  Can I turn the return value of this method (or ST if you change the method to return string) into a string.  The answer is yes.  Just use ToString() on the var.

Example...

```
GetStateByZipCode("something", "something").ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.  Because the constant variables don't change, they cannot be defined at run-time.  **Constant values can only be defined at compile time.**  Also, I wouldn't recommend storing a bool in a string.  Its good practice to stick with the correct data types.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is this...

First you cannot store a runtime value in a `const`.

So change your declaration:

```
public string MState;
```

Then you don't want to return `bool` on your method, instead return `string`

NOTE: I am adding some `using` statments to clean this up, but it is far from perfect.

```
private string GetStateByZipCode(string ZipOrPostalCode, string ST)
    {
        try
        {
            string strServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyNGConnect_ConnectionString"].ToString()))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "ngc_GetStateByZipCode";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipOrPostalCode", ZipOrPostalCode);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ST", ST);
                using (SqlDataReader reader = storedProcCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader["ZipOrPostalCode"].ToString().Equals(ZipOrPostalCode) &&
                            reader["ST"].ToString().Equals(ST))
                        {
                            return ST;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Then assign the value of `MState` somewhere like so:

```
MState = GetStateByZipCode(zipCode, state);
```

Comment: Since `MState` isn't used anywhere in the question beyond the const declaration, it's impossible to say how that would be used in a real life scenario.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I agree... I assume the OP wants to assign a value to `MState` at some point.  So I added code to assign.  Though the real question is why a method would take a state and zip code just to spit a state out (presumably the same one lol).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have a stored procedure that when a user enters their zip into a form. It return the US State that the zip is located.  I wanted that result to be used in multiple places in the code.

Comment: I'm reworking someone else code.  The value of MState is no longer assigned in the beginning.  It is pulled from a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned `const` is not a variable and its value is defined at compile time. However what you can do is define a read only property, where its value is defined within the scope of its class. In this case only that class can manipulate it and the property acts like as a readonly property (what you want instead of a const) anywhere else.

Assuming I understand what you were trying to do, this can be done like this:

```
class Address
{
  private string _state;  // the _state field 
  public string State// the State property
  {
    get
     {
        return _state;
     }
  }
  private void SetState()
  {
      if(GetStateByZipCode(string ZipOrPostalCode, string ST))
        {
           _state = "ST";
        }
      else
        {
            _state = "Not ST";
        }
  }

}
```

Somewhere else you can use the readonly property like this:

```
class OtherClass
{
   Address add = new Address();
   add.SetState();
    //Prints the value assigned to State in Class Address
   Console.Println(add.State);

   //cannot do this
   add.State = "Some Value";

 }
```

Comment: This code is supposed to show you the use of ReadOnly properties, it's not meant to be directly copy and pasted into your project. I think you should read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx